# Запросы ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql

Задача:
декартово произведение
Вывести:

- фамилии и отделы всех сотрудников из таблицы EMPLOYEES, независимо от того, относятся ли они к какому-то отделу или нет; - номера и наименования всех отделов из таблицы DEPARTMENTS, независимо от того, есть ли в них сотрудники или нет.
  Колонки отчета назвать "Last Name", "Dept Employye", "Dept Num", "Dept Name"
  Моя попытка:

  ```
       SELECT Last_Name "Last Name", department_id "Dept Employye", TO_CHAR (NULL) department_name
       FROM employees
       UNION
       SELECT (NULL), department_id "Dept Num", department_name "Dept Name"
       FROM departments
  ```

Подскажите пожалуйста,
как использовать в данном запросе CROSS JOIN?

Comment: *как использовать в данном запросе CROSS JOIN?* В данном - никак. Он вообще какой-то жестоко-бессмысленный.

Comment: Данная задача "декартово произведение", я так понимаю в Oraclr подразумевает как раз так и использование cross join